# Posting unknown amount of fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First off, let me say that I'm new to MVC so if something seem strange then that's why. I probobly don't have the right aproach so I would like some guidelines

I have a form from which the user is suppose to enter translations to a page. The translations are handled as a list of TranslationObjects to the page object. I need a way to render input fields in the form for each language branch represented on the site and let the user fill those out and post them back to the controller.
This example is just a simplification of a more complex model, but it explains the problem pretty well.

The viewmodel:

```
public class Page
{
    public List<TranslationObject> Translation { get; set; }
}

public class TranslationObject
{
    public string LanguageBranch { get; set; }
    public string PageName { get; set; }
    public string PageDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Controller for rendering the form:

```
    public ActionResult AddPage()
    {
        var model = new Page {Translation = new List<TranslationObject>()};

        foreach (var languageBranch in new[] {"en", "sv", "de"}) // These are normally loaded from database
        {
            model.Translation.Add(new TranslationObject{ LanguageBranch = languageBranch});
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
    @model MvcApplication1.Models.Page
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitPage", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        foreach (var translation in Model.Translation)
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Translation.FirstOrDefault(y => y.LanguageBranch == translation.LanguageBranch).PageName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Translation.FirstOrDefault(y => y.LanguageBranch == translation.LanguageBranch).PageName)<br/>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Translation.FirstOrDefault(y => y.LanguageBranch == translation.LanguageBranch).PageDescription)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Translation.FirstOrDefault(y => y.LanguageBranch == translation.LanguageBranch).PageDescription)
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    }
```

And controller for the post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitPage(Page model)
    {
        // Save model to db
        return View();
    }
```

The translation object of the Page model is always null. I'm aware that this is probobly the wrong aproach so I'm asking for some direction to render a list of objects and returning them to the controller when posting

Comment: User For instead of ForEach.In this case you will have the list populated on posting.Also make sure the list Translation is Initialized in constructor of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for instead of foreach.

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Page
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitPage", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Model.Translation.Count;i++)
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Translation[i].PageName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Translation[i].PageName)<br/>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Translation[i].PageDescription)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Translation[i].PageDescription)
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    }
```

And in Page Constructor initialize the Translation

Comment: How do i post the languagebranch property of the TranslationObject object back to the controller? Must i store it in a hidden field?

Comment: Yes using  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Translation[i].LanguageBranch )

Comment: What if you have some sensitive information in your viewmodel that you want to pass back to the controller. Is there a way to do that without using hiddenfields?

Comment: No, You need to implement your own encryption decryption logic for that.You can achieve it by making another property and in get block return the encrypted string and in set block decrypt the incomming value and set to original property. And use this property for making the hidden field. Alternatively you can go for custom model binder.